# Javascript selenium wait until onMouseDown listener is set

Tags: reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, onmousedown

I have a `div` (using React component), something like this:

```
    <div className="drag-tab" onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}>
      <span className="drag-icon"></span>
    </div>
```

handleMouseDown looks like this:

```
  handleMouseDown(e) {
    console.log('The mouse down event');
  }
```

I want to write acceptance test for this using selenium webdriver. Important part from my code looks like this:

```
  async function dragWidget() {
    const elem = driver.findElement(By.css('.drag-tab'));
    //await driver.sleep(1000);
    return driver
      .actions()
      .mouseDown(elem)
      // some other stuff for dragging here
      .perform()

  }
```

When I uncomment `await driver.sleep(1000);` it goes into handler and logs "The mouse down event". But without sleep it does not go there. It seems that it needs some time for setting the `onMouseDown`  listener. I have tried everything to wait until it is ready to be "mouse downed", but without any success. Thing I tried are to wait for `elementIsEnabled`, `elementLocated`, `elementIsVisible`  but they didn't work. I don't want to use `sleep` though. Note that similar thing happens if I change mouse down event with `onClick`. But I need the solution for the mouse down.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

The issue is that the div has the styles which make the element out of bound of his parent div i.e it's like that:

```
<div className="parent-div">
  <div className="drag-tab" onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}>
    <span className="drag-icon"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The styles:

```
.drag-tab {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  width: 40px;
  height: 48px;
  top: 150px;
  left: -40px;
}
```

The problem is `-40px` part which makes the div `40px left to the parent div. Weird thing is that if I change -40px to -20px the test works, -21px doesn't. (the break point seems the half of the width).

Comment: The issue seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057031/webdriver-how-to-wait-until-the-element-is-clickable-in-webdriver-c-sharp
but I'm using javascript instead of c# and also `isEnabled` and `isDisplayed` didn't work for me

Comment: Either wait for an element created by the React library (an element that is created after the listener is assigned) or wait for the `onMouseDown` property to be different from the static HTML. The recommended approach is to try to reproduce as close as possible the behavior of a user which is to wait for a rendered clue that tells you the page is ready to be interacted with.