# Selenium element being blocked by non-existent element

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to run some Selenium tests in Java but some fields are being blocked by another one and aren't clickable.  The problem is, that other field doesn't actually exist in the page source.

```
The error is: Element <select id="pets" class="sumo form-control SumoUnder" name="pets"> is not clickable at point (1025.833351135254,677.4000244140625) because another element <span> obscures it
```

There is no  element that doesn't have other tags (id, class, etc.) with it.  So what is this mysterious field?

Interestingly, if I try to access some other fields first, I get different obscuring fields, which ALSO don't exist on the page. Such as:

```
<p class="CaptionCont SelectBox">
```

Watching the test interactively doesn't help; there's nothing visible that's blocking the elements when the error's thrown.

Where are these phantom fields coming from, and how do I stop them from blocking my fields?

EDIT: I have found that these fields are being added by SumoSelect.  They don't show up when you view the source of the page, but they're there if you save the page and open it locally.

```
<div class="col form-group">
  <label for="pets">Pets</label>
  <div class="SumoSelect sumo_pets" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
    <select id="pets" name="pets" class="sumo form-control SumoUnder" tabindex="-1">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <p class="CaptionCont SelectBox" title="Select">
      <span class="placeholder">Select</span>
      <label><i></i></label>
    </p>
    <div class="optWrapper">
      <ul class="options">
          <li class="opt"><label>Select</label></li>
          <li class="opt"><label>1</label></li>
          <li class="opt"><label>2</label></li>
          <li class="opt"><label>3</label></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to wait until element is clickable, how to do it you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057031/webdriver-how-to-wait-until-the-element-is-clickable-in-webdriver-c-sharp/16057521)

Comment: How long do you think I should try?  Because I've tried that for 5 minutes, but the field never becomes clickable.

Comment: Does any of this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19763087/3124333 ? If not, you will need to post a [mcve].

Comment: I've added some info.  I discovered the page (I didn't write it) is using SumoSelect, which is creating the problem fields.

Answer (score 0):

if not clickable, may be selectable.

```
Select pets = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("pets")));
pets.selectByIndex(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a JS library to enhance the `Select` - you need to see the final DOM created by the JS library. In the case of SumoSelect - the CSS for the select box itself is:

```
<p class="CaptionCont SelectBox" title=" Volvo">
   <span> Volvo</span>
   <label><i></i></label>
</p>
```

See the `span` there? If you want to click the dropdown - you need to click that span.

Comment: Thanks!  That let me click it, but then how do I select the index I want to?  It won't let me put the span in a new Select() to use selectByIndex.

Comment: I guess you need to click the corresponding labels in the optWrap div.

Answer (score 0):

Try to click using JavaScript Executor.

Reference Link:- http://learn-automation.com/click-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java-script/