# Wait for and then click an item?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

So I would like to wait for a pop-up and then click Accept.
HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="termsBtn" onclick="checkTerms(0)" style="background-color:#dd4a42">Decline</div>

<div class="termsBtn" onclick="checkTerms(1)" style="background-color:#a6dd42">Accept</div>
```

I have tried all sorts, but for this current code I am getting a TimeoutException:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

My current code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
popup = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@onclick="checkTerms(1)"]')))
popup.click()
```

Comment: Please post the full exception message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no input tag of your element it is a div tag.Try below xpath.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
popup = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="termsBtn"][text()="Accept"]')))
popup.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated, it will wait till the element not visible

Source:

[Webdriver How to wait until the element is clickable in webdriver C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057031/webdriver-how-to-wait-until-the-element-is-clickable-in-webdriver-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

As the desired element is within a popup so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.termsBtn[onclick*='1']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='termsBtn' and text()='Accept']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```